# Changing Android files in root directory

Tags: root, embedded, android

Does anyone know how (if it is possible) to change Android files stored in root directory, particularly logo.rle? I want to change my boot splashscreen, changing the file, which is stored in `/`. I have managed to change the file with root browser. But after phone reboot, all files in `/` and `/system` revert back to their original state.

I know from embedded boards, that you have to execute `saveenv` command, so that the changes you make remain after reboot...but Android doesn't have that command, even with buisybox installed :(

Comment: I think this depends on the Android version, and for some versions on the phone or distributor as not every manufacturer builds the system in the same way. What Android version is it, on which device or from which alternate source?

Comment: I have a rooted SE WT19i with CM9 installed, I downgraded recently from CM10.